# Exclude url from flask

Tags: flask, webfaction

I have deployed a website on Webfaction using Flask app for the site's main functionality and an AWStats app for analysis. The path for this AWStats app is `/stats`, but if I try to access my stats, Flask takes over and renders a 404-error page.

How do I exclude this `/stats`-path?

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching the problem from the wrong end.

When you access the `somesite/stats` path you're asking a webserver and then an application server. Or at least this should be in a deployed environment.

It's the webserver that manages the routing. So there are plenty of ways to do this in your webserver configuration.

For example a `<Location /stats>` section in Apache or a `location /stats {}` directive in NGINX.